# Hook after meta created

Tags: custom-field, hooks

I'm having troubles trying to do a hook when post published. I think that the problem is that my WP-Metaboxer plugin creates the meta after publishing post, and I cannot capture the value.

```
Here is an example:

function post_published_coins_update( $ID, $post ) {    
        $tipo = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tipo');

        $coins_value = $tipo;

        add_user_meta($post->post_author, 'coins', $coins_value);
    }
add_action('publish_post', 'post_published_coins_update',  10, 2);
```

I've created a metabox that create a post_meta called "tipo", but the hook doesn't access to it, is like if the hook starts before than the meta creates.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a dynamic hook right before any new metadata is added:

```
do_action( "add_{$meta_type}_meta", $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );
```

It would be `add_post_meta` for posts accordingly.

Note that you might to tinker some to catch this *precisely* in the case of new post being created, for example hook into `publish_post` first, note the ID, and add to this hook from there.

Comment: Hummm... I think update_metatype_meta could be better: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_%28meta_type%29_meta

Comment: Updates fire when _updating existing_ metadata, that won't catch meta being set for the first time (as far as I remember).